# Is it possible for kubeconfig to be expired?

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I do `ibmcloud ks cluster config --cluster`, kubeconfig is stored locally with id-token and refresh-token.

So long as I have that file, the authentication appears to never expire.

Is it possible to obtain a kubeconfig that DOES expire after some period?

Comment: Do you mean other than described here? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_api_install#cs_cli_refresh

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. Maybe the answer is there, but I don't see it yet.
I think the key is if you could specify shorter duration for refresh_token